# How to scroll to the bottom of the terminal in C?

Tags: c, scroll, terminal

I want to move down (scroll to the bottom) terminal in my function, and how i can this ?

```
exemple: void Test(void) { scroll down terminal }
```

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the type of terminal -- there is no portable way to do this.

Comment: OP has not identified the terminal type, and even for those that recognize escapes, 25 lines is not standard.  By the way, cursor-addressing is not the same as scrolling.

Comment: It would help, for instance, to know if this is a Windows console window, or a terminal emulator running in Unix/BSD/Linux/etc.  But the terminal *type* really does matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested `printf("\033[25;1H");` but doesn't work for me.
It's for when i printf text, the terminal go directly on the bottom because when i scroll on the top, when i printf the terminal don't go on the bottom

Sorry for my english